# Is Delete doing anything at all in this procedure?

Tags: delphi, memory-management

In a project I received and currently I am working on, I've seen this code more than a few times when releasing items from a list.

```
while Count > 0 do
  begin
   Items[0].Free;
   Delete(0);
 end;
```

What is the purpose of that `Delete(0)` after using `Free`?

Is it a better option to call `FreeAndNil()` for the elements and then for the list, and not using `Delete`, which I can't understand why previous developers used it there.

Comment: Use a TObjectList and you get self cleaning objects :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Delete is necessary to remove the first item from the list. That way, the second item becomes the first, and the loop continues until no items are left. All `Delete` does, is removing the item, while `Free` takes care of freeing the object to which that item pointed. FreeAndNil won't help, since you would still have `nil` in the list, instead of removing it (it probably won't compile anyway, since `Item[i]` is a probably a property).

This loop can be quite inefficient, though. If this is a TList, or any other class that uses a similar array-wrapping approach, then this causes a lot of moving of memory. When you delete the first item, all the other items are actually moved in memory.

A better solution.
This one is faster, because it doesn't do a big number of array-shifting.

```
for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
  Items[i].Free;
Clear;
```

Other solutions (as per comments)

Probably just as fast as the one above. Also doesn't need array shifting, and, more importantly, you won't have stale items in your list, because they are deleted right away.

```
while Count > 0 do
begin
  Items[Count-1].Free;
  Delete(Count-1);
end;
```

Which can alternatively be written as:

```
for i := Count - 1 downto 0 do
begin
  Items[i].Free;
  Delete(i);
end;
```

Note that in a multi-threaded environment this might still cause trouble, since freeing and deleting the item isn't atomic. There are multiple ways to solve that, but I think it's out of the scope of this answer.

Even better than the solutions above:
Use a TObjectList (if it isn't already an objectlist). TObjectList has a property OwnsObject, indicating whether the objectlist should take care of cleaning up the objects in it. If that property is True, you can just call `Clear`, and it will do that freeing and deleting for you.

Comment: That's not necessarily better. If the destructor of the item ends up referring to the list you're clearing, it will see the already-freed objects. (But for most uses, yes, your version is better.)

Comment: @hvd Good point. If the object modifies or even refers to the list in its descructor, then you should be careful with this. Thanks for the warning.

Comment: To deal with @hvd's point just replace `[0]` and `(0)` in the question with `[Count-1]` and `(Count-1)`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Depends on what the object does exactly.

Comment: No. The point is that your code leaves stale references in the list while destroying the items.

Comment: That's true, but it depends on how your application works whether that's a problem. I agree that using [Count-1] and (Count-1) is a more generic (more defensive) and hence better solution, though, so let's agree to agree.

Comment: I'm not saying it's necessarily a problem. It would be an odd container where the items went poking around the rest of the container when destroyed. `Count-1` just avoids the reallocation and move cost in a cheap way. I like your approach though. I like `TObjectList<T>` even better!  ;-)

Comment: Sometimes I use something like: `for i := Count - 1 downto 0 do begin ... Delete(i); end;` By looping backwards, `Delete()` does not move items in memory, only truncates the list's internal array, and `Count` only needs to be queried once.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks. It has more or less the same effect as using `Count-1` as the index, but like you say, you call the Count function less often this way. I've added your notation to my answer, which is slowly becoming a community answer with all these suggestions. ;)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "It would be an odd container where the items went poking around the rest of the container when destroyed." -- A possible example would be a control, which when freed, tells its parent to realign its other remaining child controls. In fairness, in the VCL, that specific example is actually implemented slightly differently, but I hope it is still a useful example.

Answer (score 2):

This code is clearing a list, and destroying its members at the same time.

- The call to `Free` destroys the item.
- The call to `Delete` removes the reference to the item from the list.

If there was no call to `Delete`, the loop would never terminate. Note the loop condition, `while Count > 0`. Each iteration of the loop reduces `Count` by one until it reaches zero when the list is empty.

In modern Delphi the list would probably be replaced with `TObjectList<TMyObject>` and the list would have `OwnsObjects` set to `True`. Then a single call to `Clear` on the list would free all the members, and clear the list.

Comment: Right. And also in older versions without generics, you might use TObjectList instead of TList. Actually, this code suggests that that already is the case (calling Free without cast to TObject). TObjectList to my knowledge has always had the OwnsObjects property.

Comment: @GolezTrol Code does look a bit bogus for that very reason. If you are using `TObjectList` then surely the entire point of that is to be able to use `OwnsObjects`.